# any ideas for copy the offline data from google digital ink downloaded models?

Tags: google-mlkit

google digital ink requested an internet connection to download the recognition model data, but I have a situation that requested a completely offline environment, is there any way to use google digital ink handwrite recognition? or could I make a copy of the downloaded model data use in another project? I'v tried copy the data from data/data/package_name/files/mlkit_digital_in_recognition/datadownload/public/somedata and put them into another project with the same path, but it does not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, offline models for ML Kit Digital Ink Recognition are not supported at the moment.   Thanks for your feedback though.